# Using android:icon and android:logo together

Tags: android, android-manifest

My app currently uses both [android:icon](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#icon) and [android:logo](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#logo)?  Is there any harm done by specifying both of them in the Android.xml manifest file?

Comment: question has been rephrased

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be only one logo per application but can be different icons for different activities and the application.